# Why does my Slack bot name not accept updates?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm at a total loss here and have nowhere to turn.

I made an app, set a name as `Test App`. Working fine. Update the name under `Display Information` to `Dashboard App`. Then I click *Install your app to your workplace* and authorize it.

And... nothing.

I've restarted slack. I've waited now 8 hours. I've tried again. I changed the Bot name itself. Yet the thing still says `Test App`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To edit the app name after it has been installed, you have to find the app in the "App Directory" for your Slack workspace.

First, open Slack, tap on the workspace name ("Raikes" in this case), tap "Settings & Administration", then "Manage Apps":
[image]

Next, scroll down to "Bot User" and edit the bot name to be whatever you want:
[image]

Answer (score 23):

Found a different solution that updated immediately, which I had to do AFTER I did what was described by @plowman, to have the changes reflected in Slack:

- Right click on bot name on Slack> Open App Details
- In pop up, click Configuration, will redirect to browser tab
- In browser, scroll down to Bot User section, find edit button
- Change name and save

Answer (score 8):

In the process of writing this I figured it out.

While you can rename the bot and save, this apparently does nothing. You must *delete* the bot and add it again, then reinstall the app. This creates a new auth token and bot ID, which you must also update in your app.

Only then will the name change.

Comment: This answer is not correct. See @plowman's answer below

Answer (score 2):

previous answers only change the name of the bot in charge of acting on behalf of the app. If you want to change the name of the app itself, you could:

1. you gotta go to https://api.slack.com/apps
2. then check the app lists shown
3. select the app you want and go to the "Display Information" section
4. update the app name
5. in the end, click on the "save changes" bottom.